# Python recursion - how to exit early

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, exit

I've been playing with BST (binary search tree) and I'm wondering how to do an early exit. Following is the code I've written to find kth smallest. It recursively calls the child node's find_smallest_at_k, stack is just a list passed into the function to add all the elements in inorder. Currently this solution walks all the nodes inorder and then I have to select the kth item from "stack" outside this function.

```
def find_smallest_at_k(self, k, stack, i):
    if self is None:
        return i

    if (self.left is not None): 
        i = self.left.find_smallest_at_k(k, stack, i) 

    print(stack, i)
    stack.insert(i, self.data)
    i += 1
    if i == k: 
        print(stack[k - 1]) 
        print "Returning" 

    if (self.right is not None): 
        i = self.right.find_smallest_at_k(k, stack, i) 

    return i
```

It's called like this,

```
our_stack = []
self.root.find_smallest_at_k(k, our_stack, 0) 
return our_stack[k-1]
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to exit early from that function. If my k is say 1, I don't really have to walk all the nodes then find the first element. It also doesn't feel right to pass list from outside function - feels like passing pointers to a function in C. Could anyone suggest better alternatives than what I've done so far?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think your question is 'what's an efficient/elegant way to find the k'th (ordered) item in a binary search tree. If so then I would suggest you create an iterator that walks the tree, `yield`ing the values in order, and then have a function get_kth that just loops on the iterator, returning the kth result from it.

Comment: @TomDalton - The question was mainly to see if I could somehow cleverly arrange the base case in recursion to return the kth smallest without walking all nodes. I agree that a better approach would be to use iteration rather than recursion, but sticking to recursion for the minute is there a more efficient way to do this? I've asked this question more out of curiosity. I cannot think of a way to get out of recursion without throwing an `Exception` perhaps to unwind all stack frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Passing list as arguments:** Passing the list as argument can be good practice, *if you make your function tail-recursive*.  Otherwise it's pointless.  With BST where there are two potential recursive function calls to be done, it's a bit of a tall ask.

Else you can just *return* the list.  I don't see the necessity of variable `i`.  Anyway if you absolutely need to return multiples values, you can always use tuples like this `return i, stack` and this `i, stack = root.find_smallest_at_k(k)`.

**Fast-forwarding:** For the fast-forwarding, note the right nodes of a BST parent node are always bigger than the parent.  Thus if you descend the tree always on the right children, you'll end up with a growing sequence of values.  Thus the first `k` values of that sequence are necessarily the smallest, so it's pointless to go right `k` times or more in a sequence.

Even in the middle of you descend you go left at times, it's pointless to go more than `k` times on the right.  The BST properties ensures that if you go right, ALL subsequent numbers below in the hierarchy will be greater than the parent.  Thus going right `k` times or more is useless.

**Code:** Here is a pseudo-python code quickly made.  It's not tested.

```
def findKSmallest( self, k, rightSteps=0 ):
    if rightSteps >= k: #We went right more than k times
        return []
    leftSmallest = self.left.findKSmallest( k, rightSteps ) if self.left != None else []
    rightSmallest = self.right.findKSmallest( k, rightSteps + 1 ) if self.right != None else []
    mySmallest = sorted( leftSmallest + [self.data] + rightSmallest )
    return mySmallest[:k]
```

EDIT The other version, following my comment.

```
def findKSmallest( self, k ):
    if k == 0:
        return []
    leftSmallest = self.left.findKSmallest( k ) if self.left != None else []
    rightSmallest = self.right.findKSmallest( k - 1 ) if self.right != None else []
    mySmallest = sorted( leftSmallest + [self.data] + rightSmallest )
    return mySmallest[:k]
```

Note that if `k==1`, this is indeed the search of the smallest element.  Any move to the right, will immediately returns `[]`, which contributes to nothing.

Comment: I though of this a little and as on optimization, if you made `i` moves to the right, you know you already met at least `i` values that will be smaller than anything you will find below the current node.  Thus you can safely return only the `(k-i)` smallest elements.  In my pseudo-python-code this can be done with `return mySmallest[:k-rightSteps]` but also getting rid of the argument `rightSteps` altogether and do the following recursive call, `self.right.findKSmallest( k - 1 )`.  If `k == 0`, always return `[]`

Answer (score 0):

As said Lærne, you have to care about turning your function into a tail-recursive one; then you may be interested by using a continuation-passing style. Thus your function could be able to call either itself or the "escape" function. I wrote a module called `tco` for optimizing tail-calls; see https://github.com/baruchel/tco
Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: it doesn't *exit recursion early, instead it prevents additional function calls if not needed*, which is essentially what you're trying to achieve.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def find_smallest_at_k(root, k):
    res = [None]
    count = [k]

    def helper(root):
        if root is None:
            return

        helper(root.left)
        count[0] -= 1
        if count[0] == 0:
            print("found it!")
            res[0] = root
            return

        if count[0] > 0:
            print("visiting right")
            find(root.right)

    helper(root)
    return res[0].v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an exception when you want to stop the recursion, and then wrap the recursive call in try/catch.

For example

```
def find_smallest_at_k(self, k, stack, i):
    if self is None:
        return i

    if (self.left is not None): 
        i = self.left.find_smallest_at_k(k, stack, i) 

    print(stack, i)
    stack.insert(i, self.data)
    i += 1
    if i == k: 
        print(stack[k - 1]) 
        print "Returning" 
        raise None # <-- raise an exception

    if (self.right is not None): 
        i = self.right.find_smallest_at_k(k, stack, i) 

    return i
```

And then call the function as

```
our_stack = []
try:
    self.root.find_smallest_at_k(k, our_stack, 0)
except:
    return our_stack[k-1]
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to exit as soon as earlier possible, then use **`exit(0)`**.
This will make your task easy!

Comment: When OP say exit, OP did not mean exit out of the program but stop the recursion early for paths where the paths are not helpful for returning the correct result.